# Check for even or odd

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given N amd M how to check whether floor value of N!/M will be even value or odd value where N can go upto 10^5 and M can go upto 10^18.

Please help to check this condition in efficient way.

EDIT

My attempt : I first think of breaking N!=(2^a)(some odd value) and similarly for M but as the odd value of N! can be very large so i was thinking of some better solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would love to help you, if you'll tell us what have you tried so far! Please edit your post and provide more details on what you tried and why it isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: before even/odd, I think you should check whether the number is integer or rational number

Comment: @ikh It is assumed both are Integers

Comment: @hd1 - Must come from Somerset (as weather floor value is important) http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-somerset-26312853

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry,It was just typing error

Comment: @user132263 oh, I didn't see *floor value*..

Comment: You might want to ask this on the Mathematics discussion. I don't know of any shortcut, which would mean that the first thing you need to find is an efficient way to calculate N! -- and a numeric class which can handle many more digits of precision than the standard C++ types.

Comment: @keshlam: You can't calculate N! because N is just too large in this case. It would have in the order of 10^8 or more digits. A cleverer algorithm is needed

Comment: @user132263: Although N! is large, you can factorize it pretty easily. You can also factorize M with Pollard-Rho or similar, so that might give you an idea.

Comment: Which is why I suggested taking it to Mathematics. That's where you might find people who have the theoretical background to tell you whether such an algorithm is possible or not.

Comment: N! will always be even, unless N is 1. Because factorial is defined:


Where M is less than or N, the

Comment: @J.A.Streich: That's an interesting half sentence there ;)

Comment: N! will always be even, unless N is 1, -1. Because factorial is defined:
N*N-1*N-2* .... *2*1 ... Which means 2 is always a factor.

So, where M is less than or N, except N=3, M=2, I think the answer will always be even.

Hmmm...  where M is larger, it gets messy.

Don't know what happened that cause it to post early.

Comment: @J.A.Streich: Yes, if `M <= N` or `M >= N!`, the problem is trivial. This leaves `N! > M > N`, which is the underlying problem.